# How to connect switch to a patch panel

Tags: networking, router, switch, patch

I have a 24-port patch panel that connects Cat6 cables throughout my house. Out of these, only 12 ports are connected at the moment.

I am in the process of setting up my home network and looking at using a switch to connect (a) NAS, (b) a server/PC, and (c) ADSL modem/router; and then connect the switch to the patch panel.

Q1. What is the minimum number of ports I need for the switch based on my requirements? Do I need a minimum 15 port switch and connect each outgoing port from the patch panel to a port on the switch?

Q2. What is the best solution if I want my NAS to be shared by only 4 of the (12) currently connected ports on the patch panel, but want to share the server and ADSL connection with all 12 of them?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Are there devices connected to the other end of the 12 "connected" ports on your patch panel?  Will the NAS, server/PC, and ADSL modem/router be located physically together, or separate from each other (and if together, do I correctly assume they'll be in the same location as the patch panel and switch)?

Comment: Thanks!
Not all 12 ports are connected to devices. Some are mostly free (to connect laptops etc. when needed), and others are almost always connected (e.g. TV, Bluray, WDTV and a Wi-Fi router etc.).

You are correct to assume that they are all located physically together at the same location as the patch panel/switch.